# MongoDB deleteOne by ObjectId from Schema not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I am trying to `deleteOne` in MongoDB, however, I don't think it is working.

My code is here:

```
const deleteGroup = async (req, res) => {
  const { groupId } = req.body
  try {
    console.log(req.body)
    Group.deleteOne({_id: new ObjectId(groupId) })

    res.send(`${groupId} deleted`);
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    res.status(400).json({ err: err.message });
  }
}
```

The `console.log(groupId)` produces the right Id that I want to remove, which is (`6480898f2012404b9adbb71e`).

Am I using the deleteOne wrongly? The Group object is a schema, which is shown below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const groupSchema = new Schema({
  group_name: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  group_description: {
    type: String,
  },
  group_admin: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  group_notes: {
    type: String,
  },
  group_public: {
    type: Boolean,
    require: true
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Group', groupSchema);
```

Comment: Can you console the `deleteOne` result?

Comment: Hello, console logging `deleteOne` gives me this

```

Comment: @turivishal u can see the console.log at the  answer section

Comment: Hey, you have added your reply as an answer, you can edit your question and add your details instead of answering, well i see you need to cover your function with async and put await before the `await Group.deleteOne(..`.

Comment: just add `await` like this `await Group.deleteOne({_id: new ObjectId(groupId) })`

Comment: Hello, sorry didnt think about editting my question, but thank you @turivishal and SuleymanSah, putting await in front indeed worked! If possible you can put the answer at the bottom and i'll mark that as the correct answer. Thanks again!

Comment: no need to write answer, we can close this question